# How does setting instance variable public and not using setter method might break collaborators' code who are using my class in java?

Tags: java

I found the following passage in the book "Headfirst java". I don't understand the bolded part in the below passage.

> Object: The point to setters (and getters, too) is that you can change
>   your mind later, without breaking anybody else's code! Imagine if half
>   the people in your com- pany used your class with public instance
>   variables, and one day you suddenly realized,
>   **" Oops - there's something I didn't plan for with that value, I'm going to have to switch to a setter method." You break everyone's
>   code.** The cool thing about encapsulation is that you get to change
>   your mind. And nobody gets hurt. The performance gains from using
>   variables directly is so miniscule and would rarely be worth it.

Comment: I mean ** ~ ** part not boldface part. Thnx.

Answer (score 0):

The internal representation of that value may change and require a new type be used, which could be hidden from other code using getter/setter methods.

Comment: aha !!! then others might falsely assign it to another type that can't can take it and not be able to compile it ?? right?? ( Sorry for late reply. Thank you !!! )